# Best practice for inferring schema from a CSV file in a raw ingestion layer of a data lake?

Tags: azure, csv, schema, azure-databricks, azure-purview

Is there a best practice for inferring schema in a raw ingestion layer of a data lake (not schema validation, just infer data types and column names)?

I am using Azure and want to design a way to validate the schema downstream from the ingestion layer, so therefore want a way to infer it from a CSV in order to do the validation.

So far I have tried to read a csv with integers using Azure Data Factory and write to AVRO because of the schema in the header and it stored all as strings. I also tried to scan the files (CSV and AVRO) with Purview but still returned all strings.

File Format: NAICS Company Number, NAICS Company Name, Column for each state (w a value of 1 or 0)

I think the obvious answer may be to use Spark (Databricks) but I want to make sure I go with a simple / necessary rationale for needing to suggest this.

Edit: We need to do this dynamically as we will be running it daily and for a pipeline that ingests many csvs (not just one file).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand correctly but you could get something like this. Which will resul in struct and that could be used to validate your file.

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv")
     .option("header","true")
     .option("inferSchema","true")
     .load("/FileStore/tables/retail-data/by-day/2010_12_01.csv")

val scheme = df.schema
```

results in:
scheme: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(InvoiceNo,StringType,true), StructField(StockCode,StringType,true), StructField(Description,StringType,true), StructField(Quantity,IntegerType,true), StructField(InvoiceDate,StringType,true), StructField(UnitPrice,DoubleType,true), StructField(CustomerID,DoubleType,true), StructField(Country,StringType,true))